# Are there memory leaks in Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, macos, memory-leaks, operating-system

This question is purely theoretical.

I was wondering whether the *Linux source code* could have memory leaks, and how they debugged it, considering that it is Linux, after all, that deals with each program's memory?

I obviously understand that Linux, being written in C, has to deal itself with `malloc` and `free`. What I don't understand is how we measure the operating system's memory leaks.

Note that this question is not Linux-specific; it also addresses the corresponding issues in Windows and MacOS X (darwin).

Comment: In all likelihood, yes, there are memory leaks somewhere. It's near impossible to write that much code without a single memory leak (even if you're the world's best C programmers). As to how they debug it, idk.

Comment: All code has bugs; some of those bugs will result in memory leaks. This includes OS code. However since OS are required to run for days/weeks/months without rebooting, you can expect those bugs to be minimized to a minor level.

Comment: All code has bugs...umm not mine! Never!  Well at least I haven't found any and none of my user's have reported any..nope not me!

Comment: @Mark I sure do hope they are minimized! But since I cannot make a benchmark, how would I, say, check which operating system has most leaks?

Comment: @Thaddee, the conditions that trigger a memory leak are likely to be highly specific to what you're doing on the system, as well as the OS itself. If I knew how to trigger bugs automatically I wouldn't be working for a living! The typical uptime of the OS you're considering would have a good correlation, and might be a more useful measure to you than pure leakage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite frequently non-mainstream drivers and the staging tree has memory leaks.  Follow the LKML and you can see occasional fixes for mistakes in the networking code for corner cases handling lists of SKBs.

Due to the nature of the kernel most work is code review and refactoring, but work is ongoing to make more tools:

http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/Google_Summer_of_Code#kmemtrace_-_Kernel_Memory_Profiler

In certain cases you can use frameworks like Usermode Linux and then use conventional tools like Valgrind to attempt to peer into the running code:

http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of malloc and free (actually brk/sbrk, since malloc and free are implemented by libc in-process) are not magical or special - it's just code, just like anything else, and there are data structures behind it that describe the mappings.

If you want to test correct behavior, one way is to write test programs in user-space that are known to allocate then free all their memory correctly. Run the app, then check the internal memory allocation structures in kernel mode using a debugger (or better yet, make this check a debug assert on process shutdown).

Comment: That should check whether `malloc` and `free` work ok, but what about the operating system code?

Comment: This is where the kernel debugger comes in.

Answer (score 1):

All software has bugs, including operating systems. Some of those bugs will result in memory leaks.

The Linux has a kernel debugger to help track down these things, but one has to discover that they exist before one can track them down. Usually, once a bug has been discovered and can be replicated at will, it becomes much easier to fix (Relatively speaking! Obviously you need a good coder to do the job). The hard part is finding the bugs in the first place and creating reliable test cases that demonstrate them. This is where you need to have a skilled QA team.

So I guess the short version of this answer is that good QA is as important good coding.